# How to update a column's value using row number in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I want to update a column's value in this way

```
new value  = old value + row_number() * 1000
```

also for row_number I want to use order by old value

but I didn't find any solution.

sample data

```
column    
   1
   3
   5
```

after update query it should be

```
column
  1001
  2003
  3005
```

Comment: can you please provide some sample data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE test, NO FALLBACK
(MyCol SMALLINT NOT NULL)
PRIMARY INDEX (MyCol)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO test VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (5);

SELECT MyCol FROM test;

UPDATE test
  FROM (SELECT MyCol
             , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MyCol) AS RowNum_
          FROM test) DT1
   SET MyCol = test.MyCol + (RowNum * 1000)
 WHERE test.MyCol DT1.MyCol;

SELECT MyCol FROM TEST;
```